# Where can I find bcp for boost?

Tags: boost

I have a program that needs to be tested on multiple machines. I've used the program_options library from boost, and would like to include it with my source so I don't have to install boost on every machine.

It seems that `bcp` takes care of this, but for the life of me I can't find where to actually download bcp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its sources are distributed with Boost. You can find them in boost/tools/bcp.
In order to build it, go to the above directory and run ..\..\b2.exe

Comment: To expand, I'm using OSX and installed boost through homebrew.bcp was not included with the brew package installation, so I had to download the boost source from the website.

Comment: For OSX bcp has since been added to homebrew, see @aaronman's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21712746/276457).

Answer (score 6):

Easier answer for mac only.

```
brew install boost-bcp
```

You might have to link it too but homebrew spoon feeds it to you

```
brew link boost-bcp
```

You can just run it with bcp, be careful because homebrew also has bcp (Broadcast Copy)